# How to set the output of the aws-sdk-go to "text"?

Tags: json, go, text, aws-cli, aws-sdk-go

Although the `output` setting has been set to `text`

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
output=text
```

the [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) returns `json`. The question is whether the output could be switched to `text`.

When:

```
aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id some-id
```

is run, the output looks as follows:

```
NAMESERVERS some-ns
NAMESERVERS some-ns1
NAMESERVERS some-ns2
NAMESERVERS some-ns3
```

According to the [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/sessions.html) one could set the configuration:

> ```
> sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
>     Region: aws.String("us-east-2")},
> )
> ```

One attempt was [to consult this Config struct](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/config.go#L33), but an `Output` option seems to be omitted.

How to set the output to text?

**Note:** [an issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/3263) has added to the github page of the aws-sdk-go as well.

**Example**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/route53"
)

func main() {
    session, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r53 := route53.New(session)

    listParams := &route53.ListResourceRecordSetsInput{
        HostedZoneId: aws.String("some-id"),
    }
    records, err := r53.ListResourceRecordSets(listParams)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

returns:

```
{
  IsTruncated: false,
  MaxItems: "100",
  ResourceRecordSets: [
    {
      Name: "some-domain.",
      ResourceRecords: [{
          Value: "some-ip"
        }],
      TTL: 7200,
      Type: "A"
    }
}
```

while `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id some-id`, results in:

```
RESOURCERECORDSETS      some-domain.     7200    A
RESOURCERECORDS some-ip
```

---

**Problem**

While it is possible to set the format of the aws-cli to output, it does not seem to be possible to do the same for the SDK.

---

**Question**

How to let the go-aws-sdk return `text` rather than `json`?

Comment: Output of what? The SDK doesn't print results to terminal, that's left up to the application. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You're not outputting JSON (you can tell because the field names aren't in quotes). You're outputting Go objects, because you're just taking a Go object and printing it. The SDK is just that, an SDK; it returns you objects, it's up to you to do whatever you need to do with them - and that includes formatting them however you want to if and when you output them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all of the information you need, you just have to unravel it from the response (records).

To get similar results from the last cli command:

```
for _, recordSet := range records.ResourceRecordSets {
    log.Println("RESOURCERECORDSETS " + *recordSet.Name + strconv.Itoa(int(*recordSet.TTL)) + *recordSet.Type)
    for _, record := range recordSet.ResourceRecords {
        log.Println("RESOURCERECORDS " + *record.Value)
    }
    log.Println("")
}
```